# Loading mp3 to AudioClip at runtime in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mp3

How can I load mp3 file from filesystem to AudioClip object?

I can load ogg or wav using `WWW` class, and play it with Audio Source component, but on Windows mp3 is not supported.

Or use an external library, like NAudio. But I'm using `AudioSource.GetSpectrumData()` to visualize some game elements, and can't find similar method in NAudio.

What should i use to play audio from file, and analyze it?